# what kind of mathematical function describes this shape

Tags: functions, parametric

I've looking for curves that describes the outer and/or inner rim of this shape in cartesian space. Could someone point me to the right direction, or is there any tool I can use to get function from shape? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I think this needs clarification, are the shapes circular arcs or something else. Or are you looking for anything in that general shape?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curves like this generally require polar form. We have a fixed radius and we increase it or decrease it periodically: this motivates addition/subtraction by a wave of constant sign. We want $9$ repetitions, and since the *absolute value* of a sine or cosine wave is $\pi$ periodic, to get $9$ periods in $2\pi$ we must scale the angle by $9/2$.

[image: Graph]

Comment: Very nice solution and (+1) for sure.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you sir

Comment: thanks. so elegant.